# Tiempo de respuesta en consulta compleja

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

en una aplicación que he realizado, necesito extraer bastantes datos, y exportarlos a un excell, pero la consulta tarda mucho tiempo en realizarse y me arroja un error 504. A continuación os pongo el código que ejecuta la consulta a ver si me podéis ayudar a hacerla mas eficiente y tardar menos tiempo.

```
public function view(): View
        {
   Carbon::setLocale('es');
   $fini = new Carbon($this->fini);
   $ffin = new Carbon($this->ffin);
   $dfini = ($fini->day);
   $dffin = ($ffin->day);
   $patients = Patient::where('attention', true)
   ->select('record','name','sex','dateattention')->get();
   $profesionales = Professional::all();
   $datospatientprof=array();
   $datosfinales=array();
   $dia = $fini;
   foreach ($patients as $patient) {
      foreach ($profesionales as $profesional) {
         for ($i = $dfini; $i <= $dffin; $i++) {
            $d1 = Intervention::where('date', $dia)
            ->where('patient_record', $patient->record)
            ->where('professional_id', $profesional->id)
            ->whereIn('place_id', [1])
            ->whereIn('type_id', [1, 3, 5, 13])->count('interventions.id');
            $d2 = Intervention::where('date', $dia)
            ->where('patient_record', $patient->record)
            ->where('professional_id', $profesional->id)
            ->whereIn('place_id', [2, 3])
            ->whereIn('type_id', [1, 3, 5, 13])
            ->count('interventions.id');
            $d3 = Intervention::where('date', $dia)
            ->where('patient_record', $patient->record)
            ->where('professional_id', $profesional->id)
            ->whereIn('place_id', [1])
            ->whereIn('type_id', [2, 4, 6])
            ->count('interventions.id');
            $d4 = Intervention::where('date', $dia)
            ->where('patient_record', $patient->record)
            ->where('professional_id', $profesional->id)
            ->whereIn('place_id', [2, 3])
            ->whereIn('type_id', [2, 4, 6])
            ->count('interventions.id');
            $d5 = User_intervention::join('interventions', 
            'interventions.id', '=', 'user_interventions.interventions_id')
            ->where('interventions.date', $dia)
            ->where('user_interventions.patient_record', $patient->record)
            ->where('interventions.professional_id', $profesional->id)
            ->whereIn('interventions.place_id', [1])
            ->whereIn('interventions.type_id', [9, 12])
            ->count('user_interventions.id');
            $d6 = User_intervention::join('interventions', 
            'interventions.id', '=', 'user_interventions.interventions_id')
            ->where('interventions.date', $dia)
            ->where('user_interventions.patient_record', $patient->record)
            ->where('interventions.professional_id', $profesional->id)
            ->whereIn('interventions.place_id', [2, 3])
            ->whereIn('interventions.type_id', [9, 12])
            ->count('user_interventions.id');
            $d7 = User_intervention::join('interventions', 
            'interventions.id', '=', 'user_interventions.interventions_id')
            ->where('interventions.date', $dia)
            ->where('user_interventions.patient_record', $patient->record)
            ->where('interventions.professional_id', $profesional->id)
            ->whereIn('interventions.place_id', [1])
            ->whereIn('interventions.type_id', [10])
            ->count('user_interventions.id');
            $d8 = User_intervention::join('interventions', 
            'interventions.id', '=', 'user_interventions.interventions_id')
            ->where('interventions.date', $dia)
            ->where('user_interventions.patient_record', $patient->record)
            ->where('interventions.professional_id', $profesional->id)
            ->whereIn('interventions.place_id', [2, 3])
            ->whereIn('interventions.type_id', [10])
            ->count('user_interventions.id');
            $datospatientprof['nhist'] = $patient->record;
            $datospatientprof['nombre'] = $patient->name;
            $datospatientprof['sexo'] = $patient->sex;
            $iniatenc = new Carbon($patient->dateattention);
            $datospatientprof['inicioatencion'] = $iniatenc;
            $datospatientprof['duracionestancia'] = 
            $iniatenc->diffInMonths($ffin);
            $datospatientprof['profesional'] = $profesional->category;
            $datospatientprof[$dia->format("d-m-Y").'-aiuc'] = $d1;
            $datospatientprof[$dia->format("d-m-Y").'-aium'] = $d2;
            $datospatientprof[$dia->format("d-m-Y").'-aifc'] = $d3;
            $datospatientprof[$dia->format("d-m-Y").'-aifm'] = $d4;
            $datospatientprof[$dia->format("d-m-Y").'-aguc'] = $d5;
            $datospatientprof[$dia->format("d-m-Y").'-agum'] = $d6;
            $datospatientprof[$dia->format("d-m-Y").'-agfc'] = $d7;
            $datospatientprof[$dia->format("d-m-Y").'-agfm'] = $d8;
            $dia->addDays(1);
         }
         $dia->subDays($dffin);
         $datosfinales[]=$datospatientprof;
      }
   }
   return view('indicators.excell')
   ->with(compact('datosfinales','dia','ffin','dfini','dffin'));
}
```

Comment: Porque hacer tantas consultas a `Intervention` no podrias traerte todas en uno y despues trabajar con los resultados?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haría seria lo siguiente:

Primero recupero todos los datos con los que tengo que trabajar:

```
$todosI = Intervention::where('date', $dia)
->where('patient_record', $patient->record)
->where('professional_id', $profesional->id);
```

Posterior a esto ya no hago consultas a la base de datos si no directamente a la colección de datos extraídos anteriormente:

```
$d1=$todosI->whereIn('place_id', [1])->whereIn('type_id', [1, 3, 5, 13])->count();
$d2=$todosI->whereIn('place_id', [2, 3])->whereIn('type_id', [1, 3, 5, 13])->count();
$d3=$todosI->whereIn('place_id', [1])->whereIn('type_id', [2, 4, 6])->count();
$d4=$todosI->whereIn('place_id', [2, 3])->whereIn('type_id', [2, 4, 6])->count();
```

Y de similar forma para tus otros 4 `$d`s.

Comment: Muchas gracias Shassain, la verdad es que no pensaba que hubiese tanta diferencia, pero ha funcionado.